# Display only in SF from external api request

Tags: rest-api, external

All the documentation I see about external apis seems to suggest that the response/results need to be saved in salesforce in order to be displayed in the salesforce ui. I'm new to salesforce so please forgive me if I do not ask the question correctly.

my use case:

In salesforce frontend/ui I need to display a grid container with some basic standard controls, such as, pagination, navigate forward / reverse, filter, display order, etc... basic controls for a list of data.

I want to populate this grid with data from an external api request, and not persist the response to salesforce.

my question is: how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, your understanding is incorrect. Persistence to Salesforce is not a requirement. All you need to do is write some Apex to call the API, and return it to the client, which may be Visualforce, Aura Components, or Lightning Web Components. This answer is intentionally generic, because there's a lot of possible options.

Comment: much appreciated, down the rabbit hole I go :)

Comment: @PhillPafford I think I actually have some old code laying around here that demonstrates this. I'll see if I can find something to send you.